# How can I get Teradata SQL Assistant to autocomplete my columns while writing queries

Tags: sql, teradata

Just installed Teradata SQL Assistant 13.0 and I would like for it to display a list of columns within the table I'm selecting while building the query.

Example:

`SELECT *  FROM TABLE1 T WHERE T.`(DROP-DOWN LIST APPEAR HERE)

Is this possible in this application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Assistant 13.10 does not offer auto-completion. You may want to look at the Teradata Studio Express client (available for download [here](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-studio-express)).

Answer (score 2):

Teradata SQL Assistant DOES provide code completion, including the use of Aliases.
However you will need version 13.11 or higher.

Teradata Studio Express also supports code completion for table/view names but it does not support aliases.

Answer (score 0):

assuming anyone goes back to this thread and the version you are running is version 13.11 or higher.

To add the autofill/complete/suggest drop down thing-

it is in tools > options > Code Editor > Display Suggestions